# Why does my ExtJS 5 app return Unrecognized alias: layout.fit

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to convert our ExtJS 4.2.2 app to ExtJS 5.

I have the app successfully building with Sencha Cmd 5.

But the app does not display in the browser, so in app.js I commented out everything but creation of the viewport, and have made it so the viewport only has a button.

When I run the app I get this error in Firebug:

Unrecognized alias: layout.fit

Comment: Did you require `Ext.layout.container.Fit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this to the requires and it worked:

```
Ext.layout.container.Fit
```

Comment: I think I asked a valid question, and drove the thread to a useful and successful answer. Why the down vote? Now I can't ask questions in stack overflow, which I rely on for good technical answers. Please help.